# How to fill in blank columns left by a figure, in IEEE double column format?

Tags: tables, two-column, ieeetran, ieee-style

In IEEE Systems Journal format;

i am trying to insert a table/figure that is quite wide, so it will take up a whole column.

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{tabularx}   
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]

\onecolumn
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{LUL }}} \\
    \hline
    \centering\arraybackslash Title & \centering\arraybackslash Overview & \centering\arraybackslash Advantage(s) & \centering\arraybackslash Disadvantage(s) \\
    \hline
    Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline   
    Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline     Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline     Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline     Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline     Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline 
    \end{tabularx}
    \twocolumn

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

However, by using  \onecolumn switch followed by \twocolumn switch leaves me with the following problem;

[image: Space being left due to table]

There is a lot of space left by the figure/table, as you can see the red circle i highlighted in the attached picture, which is bad for presentation and also unacceptable by my advisor. Is there any way i can fill this empty space ?

preferably by the text that will come **after** the table/figure ?

Comment: `\onecolumn` is  a forced page break, so if you use that you need to move some text "by hand" to fill the space. But this is exactly why latex has a floating `table` environment, put the table in `\begin{table*}...` and it wll be inserted avoiding the bad page break.

Comment: please fix your example so people can run it to see the issue

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i fixed it , please check again - also, when i try by `\begin{table*}.., it gets really weird. can you provide a MWE on how i can use `table*` for my case. you can use my table code if you need to

Comment: you should clean up your preamble,why load graphicx 3 times for example?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, ofcourse. I am in a bit of a hurry right now, but i will definitely clean it up sir !

Comment: Really you should remove _all_ packages not involved in the question when asking here, have a thought for the people you are asking to trace the code. pstricks for example....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` are forced page breaks, so if you use them you have to move text "by hand". This is why LaTeX provides floating tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} % allows algorithms to be displayed PROPERLY, so use with algorithmic package
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % this pkg allowed words inside msc diagrams to be bold !
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{cuted}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% \usepackage{lmodern,babel,adjustbox,booktabs,multirow}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage{cuted}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]



\begin{table*}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{LUL }}} \\
    \hline
    \centering\arraybackslash Title & \centering\arraybackslash Overview & \centering\arraybackslash Advantage(s) & \centering\arraybackslash Disadvantage(s) \\
    \hline
    Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline   
    Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline     Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline     Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline     Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline     Duis leo. & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna  & Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna \\ \hline 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: MASSIVE THANKS for this amazing help !!